# Can gamma function be a valid solution of the functional equation $g(x+1)=(x+1)g(x)$

Tags: calculus

I got a question in my test as follows:

> $$e^{f(x)}=g(x)\quad,\quad g(x+1)=g(x) $$Find $f'(x+1)-f'(x)$

I had done it without the gamma function but while discussion I had asked that
$g(x)$ seems to satisfy a factorial pattern, so maybe I could use $g(x)=\Gamma(x)$
as standard solution but my teacher said that gamma function is not equivalent to the factorial function. But I think I am correct.

Please tell if I am correct or wrong. If I am wrong I will be happy to correct myself.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your title does not seem to match your question.  The gamma function is one solution (but not the only one) for the functional equation $g(x+1) = x g(x)$, but not $g(x+1) = (x+1) g(x)$..

Comment: In gamma function differentials are infinitesimal, for factorials the $ n$'s differ by unity.